# How to add dynamic filename path in IBM DB2 IMPORT Command?

Tags: sql, import, db2, etl, db2-luw

I am working on ETL process from CSV to DB2 using DB2 utility. The challenge is to assign dynamic file name as db2 variable in import command.
Here are the sample codes,

```
connect to database;
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE filenamePath VARCHAR(225);
SET filenamePath= concat(concat('Z:/directory/file_',ts_fmt(current timestamp - 2 DAY,'ddmmyyyy')),'.csv');
import from '@filenamePath' of DEL SKIPCOUNT 1 insert into table;
connect reset;
```

Here ts_fmt is a stored procedure for getting date in specific format. I am getting output for @filenamePath

If I run the below statement,

```
select @filenamePath FROM sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

i will get output like,

```
Z:/directory/file_13092017.csv
```

But for the import command, I am getting file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading from various resources, it is confirmed that we cannot use db2 variable in db2 import utility. Since import command will not read db2 variables value.
So i created a system variable instead and used the same in import command. It works.

Open DB2 CLP as administrator and Run the following commands.

[image: My Sample Code]

Previously I used DB2 variable for getting filename.

Now i am using last modified file command (Windows cmd) to get the same file name. This is what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because IMPORT is not an SQL statement and so it cannot benefit from accessing RDBMS variables.  You can either generate a unique command-string for each csv-file, or you can use capabilities of ETL-tooling, or you can use any number of scripting languages to create the command-string for each import dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the command string for `IMPORT` and then use it as parameter to the [ADMIN_CMD](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012547.html) procedure. The procedure takes a string with the entire command including options as a single input parameter.